# Applying for a Type D (long stay) Schengen Visa for Belgium

Tags: visa, working-visas, resident-permit, belgium, philippine-citizens

I will be applying for a Type D (long stay) Schengen Visa for Belgium this September and I am from Philippines. A host family already contacted me to be their next au pair and we are now discussing things together with their agency for the requirements for my visa application and my work permit for Belgium. Regarding the visa application, I would like to ask if I need to provide documents that would prove my strong ties here in Philippines. If yes, what are the kind of documents that I need to bring? I do not own a house or rent an apartment and I do not also have a bank account with large amount of savings. I am also still living with my parents and I do not support them yet financially. I just graduated from the university last year and I already have my professional license as a teacher. However I was not employed yet as a teacher here in a public or private school. After I graduated, I was employed as a tutor in a tutorial center and as of now I am employed in a call center as a customer service representative earning a low salary.

Do au pair visa applicants need to prove their strong ties in their home country especially if they will apply for a Schengen visa? I am aware that it is common among U.S visa applicants to prove their strong ties in their home country in any non-immigrant visa applications, however I'm not really sure in the case of Schengen visa application especially if I will be an au pair in Belgium.

I have read in a website some supporting documents for U.S. visa application to prove the strong ties in the home country. I wonder if I could also present these for my Schengen visa appl;ication if ever I need to prove my strong ties in Philippines. The possible documents I could provide are the following:

A sworn affidavit from your parents listing all the family members who live in your home country, and including details to show that they are all firmly settled there. Even better, include a statement of why you, too, are likely to return (especially if there is a family business or property).

*--I am not really sure how to provide this. What is this affidavit called? Can you give a sample format of this affidavit?*

Documentation of your career potential in your home country, including statistics from a reputable source, such as your government, showing that people with your skills are in high demand; or a letter from a potential employer.

*--Teachers as far as I know are in demand in the Philippines, and I am already a professional teacher myself. I wonder how can I provide a document stating this.*

Professional Licenses: If you have any kind of professional license that could expire unless you return home.

*--As mentioned, I have a professional teaching license in Philippines. It will expire on October 2017 and can be renewed. My au pair contract is just one year and the possible start date is on December 2015 so that would end on December 2016. Can I just present my license along with the other documents?*